# SQL Server : SELECT particular row from GROUPED BY result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, subquery

I have a problem where my query needs to select the `TransactionDateTime` from `ActivityId = 6` instead of the date value from `ActivityId 66`.

The data set looks like:

```
HistoryId | CardId | ActivityId | TransactionId | TransactionDateTime
----------+--------+------------+---------------+----------------------------------
393338052   58329067    12  937DB39B-711B-E611-80D3-0025B5560BDC  2016-06-01 01:43:28.307   
393342190   58329067    13  NULL    2016-06-01 01:50:02.243  2016-06-01 01:50:02.243
393506845   58329067     6  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  2016-06-01 08:51:44.640   
393506845   58329067    66  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  2016-06-03 09:01:20.017   
385651974   58329067     5  937DB39B-711B-E611-80D3-0025B5560BDC  2016-05-16 14:23:14.560   
385596117   58329067    16  NULL    2016-05-16 13:10:16.600  2016-05-16 13:10:16.600
```

My query at the moment looks like the following:

```
SELECT 
    CC.[CreditCardId],
    CC.[ActivityId],
    CC.[TransactionDateTime],
FROM 
    dbo.[CreditCard] CC WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    CC.[ActivityId] = 66
    AND CC.[VANTransactionDateTime] >= @ReportStartDate
    AND CC.[VANTransactionDateTime] < @ReportEndDate
```

However I need modify the query to output the TransactionDateTime from the ActivityId 6 row instead of TransactionDateTime from ActivityId 66. Everything else needs to come from the ActivityId 66 row. Both of 6 and 66 rows have the same Card Id and same TransactionId.

I believe this could be achieved by inserting the distinct CardIDs, grouping them by CardID and TransactionId into a temp table, then using this to extract the 6 row. But I'm wondering if this operation could be done in the single query operation, perhaps by using aggregate functions with the group by.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear. Maybe it will helps to show use what is the expected output ?

Comment: From what I understood you want `max` activityID and `min` transactiondate with `group by` cardId

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a subquery to handle this problem

```
SELECT 
    CC.[CreditCardId],
    CC.[ActivityId],
    (SELECT TransactionDateTime 
     FROM dbo.[CreditCard] AS cs 
     WHERE Cs.[ActivityId] = 6 and cs.CardId = cc.CardId) AS [TransactionDateTime]
FROM 
    dbo.[CreditCard] CC WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    CC.[ActivityId] = 66
    AND CC.[VANTransactionDateTime] >= @ReportStartDate
    AND CC.[VANTransactionDateTime] < @ReportEndDate
```

Try to put some examples, sometimes it is difficult to guess what you want, i hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aggregation and group by for your result:

You can use min activityID as it has same CC.historyid,
    CC.[CreditCardId] and 
for transactiondate you need to use maximum so it will give you date of activity id 66

```
SELECT 
    CC.historyid,    
    CC.[CreditCardId],
    min(CC.[ActivityId]) as activityid,
    max(CC.[TransactionDateTime]) as TransactionDateTime,
FROM 
    dbo.[CreditCard] CC WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    CC.[historyId] = '393506845'
    AND CC.[VANTransactionDateTime] >= @ReportStartDate
    AND CC.[VANTransactionDateTime] < @ReportEndDate
GROUP BY 
    CC.historyid, CC.[CreditCardId]
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any of your data to test this with, but you might try something along the lines of

```
SELECT CC.[CreditCardId],
CC.[ActivityId],
LJ.[TransactionDateTime],
FROM dbo.[CreditCard] CC WITH(NOLOCK)

Left Join (Select * From dbo.[CreditCard] Where [ActivityID] = 6 ) As LJ WITH(NOLOCK)
On  CC.[CreditCardId]  = LJ.[CreditCardId]
And CC.[HistoryId]    = LJ.[HistoryId]

WHERE CC.[ActivityId] = 66
AND CC.[VANTransactionDateTime] >= @ReportStartDate
AND CC.[VANTransactionDateTime] < @ReportEndDate
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a nested select and do a simple conversion on the column before using it in the criteria

SELECT ... FROM 
   (
      SELECT ...,
          CASE WHEN LEN([ActivityId])=1 THEN CONCAT('0',[ActivityId]) ELSE CAST([ActivityId] AS VARCHAR()) END AS ActivityId FROM dbo.CreditCard) as CC
WHERE CC.ActivityId='06' ;